# Compiler ignoring if statements

Tags: c, if-statement, assembly, compiler-construction, msp430

This is probably a simple problem so, I hope you can point me in the right direction.

I am writing a simple IO program in C. In the middle of my program, I have an if statement that is never executed. I realized this when I tried to put a break point within the if statement just to have it automatically removed and pushed down past the if statement block. Diving into the problem even further, the c compiler doesn't create any assembly code for my if statement. The following are my code snippet and assembly output.

CODE:

```
void sendData(unsigned int val1 ){
    P1OUT |= 1;
    if ((val1 & 0x8000 ) == 0x8000)
        wait(T1H);
    else
        wait(T1L);
    P1OUT &= ~(1);
}
```

*NOTE: Yes, I do have another function called wait that delays a number of cycles.

ASSEMBLY:

```
 13     P1OUT |= 1;
      sendData():
 c0ae:   D3D2 0021           BIS.B   #1,&Port_1_2_P1OUT
 18     P1OUT &= ~(1);
 c0b2:   C3D2 0021           BIC.B   #1,&Port_1_2_P1OUT
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe a shareware compiler? "Register to get `if` statements"?

Comment: How are you compiling? (Or, more accurately, with what are you compiling?)

Comment: I'm using Code Composer Studio v6. Compiler: TI v4.3.1 .

Comment: It seems as though the compiler might be optimizing out that portion of code.  Does the compiler have a non-optimization setting?

Comment: `sendData` in the C version, `sendLedData` in the asm version. Are you looking at the correct function?

Comment: In code composer studio: Project → Properties → Build → MSP430 Compiler → Optimization → Optimization level.

Comment: I am sure it does, however, I have set that property to off. (Advanced Debug Optimization... --optimize_with_debug, -mn ... is off)

Comment: -Jester - Sorry about that, I edited the function upon posting this question. It is the correct function. My apologies.

Comment: Optimization level is 0 - Register Optimizations... I'll switch it to off and see.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to post the code to the wait() function?

Comment: It's working now. That optimization level was causing a problem. Thank you everyone. Yes, switching the level all the way to off worked.

Comment: You should probably get to the bottom of this - find out whether it's a compiler bug , or a valid optimization that you don't understand

Comment: If you provide more of the code, basically the source for the wait, and what calls sendData() it may be obvious to us why it was optimized out.  I suspect this is not a bug and simply an optimization you didnt understand, as this happens very often that wait loops and other similar code to this is optimized out.  And there are various solutions to still get to use the optimizer but not lose code.

Comment: Generally not a good idea to name your functions after library functions.  Best to choose a unique-r (it's a word!!) name.  DelayWait, sentwait, something...   Duplicate names can cause... weirdness. (demons fly out of your nose?)

Answer (score 5):

Wait is probably a busy loop that is getting optimized out.   I believe there is an example of a good wait function that will survive optimization in the sample code.

See for example http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/18638.aspx